# Rshiny: creating interactive ggplot from uiOutput/input

Tags: r, shiny

This is my first post, sorry if I miss anything I needed to add beforehand/if something doesn't make sense. I'm new to rshiny but I am having trouble retrieving users' choices (choice of senator and number of words) to make interactive graphs. I'm not sure how to get the senator list drop-down to be accounted for when making the graph, I thought I had it but it says it can't read output 'senator' and I think it's because I'm using uiOuput so it's different than if I were to call selectInput's inputID. Any suggestions are welcome! My code is below (I removed some sensitive information):

u.r

```
ui <- dashboardPage( dashboardHeader(title = "title"), 
     dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Main", tabName = "Main", icon = icon("r-project")),
    menuItem("ReadMe", tabName = "ReadMe", icon = icon("readme"))
    )
  ),

  dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(
      tabName = "Main",
      sidebarPanel(
        helpText("help text"),
        uiOutput('senator'),
        
        sliderInput(
          "a",
          label = "Select value to view top common words",
          min = 1,
          max = 10,
          value = 5
          ),
        ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("plot")
    )
     
    ),
    tabItem(tabName = "ReadMe", 
            includeMarkdown("README.md"))
    ),
  )
)
```

server.r

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

senators <- read.csv("senators.csv")
output$senator <- renderUI({
  selectInput("variablex",
              label = "Choose a U.S Senator from the list",
              selected = senators$name,
              choices = senators$name)
  })

  sen <- read.csv("tweet20.csv")
  person <- reactive({
    #req(output$senator)
    df <- tweet20 %>% filter(input$variablex %in% input$variablex) %>%
      group_by(year) %>% 
      top_n(input$a, n) %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      arrange(word, -n)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
      person() %>%  mutate(word = reorder(word, n)) %>%
      ggplot(person(), aes(word, n, fill = factor(year))) +
      geom_col(show.legend = FALSE) +
      facet_wrap(~ year, scales = "free") + scale_fill_viridis_d() +
      coord_flip() + labs(y="Word frequency", x="Term", title = paste("Top words used in 2020"))
    
  })



}
```

edit: I made some changes and the errors I now get is -  problem with `filter()` input `input$variablex %in% output$senator`and it can't read output 'senator' FIXED
new edit: I made changes to the code from gss' suggestion and now I get an error  in output$textPlot <- renderPlot({ : object 'output' not found. Am i missing something? I didn't really change anything with the plot

Comment: I would move the entire selectInput into the `sidebarPanel()`. Once you've done that you can switch every `output$senator` for `input$senator`. Personally I've never used renderUI(), since that's for when you want the actual app layout to change. You are only wanting the plot to change based on the senator input.

Comment: It should be enough if you change `output$senator` into `input$variablex`, no need to touch `renderUI`

Comment: thanks! changing output$senator into input$variablex helped! However, I now get error of object 'output' not found when running the plot

Comment: But did you change this line: `output$senator <- renderUI({`? You shouldn't. I meant to change all occurences of `output$senator` *except* occurence in this line: `output$senator <- renderUI({`. LATER: Ok, I see your edit now. Why do you have `output$textPlot <- renderPlot({`. I mean, why `output$textPlot`? Shouldn't be `output$plot`? I see in your `ui.R` in `mainPanel` I see `plotOutput('plot')`, not `plotOutput('textPlot')`

Comment: yes, I caught that soon after! I fixed it on my end. Thanks again!!